# Running the training operation multiple times in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, you could use the following code to run train_step 1000 times:

```
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss=loss)

for _ in range(1000):
    sess.run(train_step)
```

Is there a way to do this using tensorflow's while loop?

I tried using the while loop below, but nothing gets trained:

```
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 1000)
def body(i):
    with tf.control_dependencies([train_step]):
        return i+1
r = tf.while_loop(c, body, [i])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    result = sess.run(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a tensorflow while loop to run the training step multiple times the body function passed to `tf.while_loop` has to be a python function which computes the training step tensor from scratch from the input tensors.

So something like

```
def body(i):
  data = iterator.get_next()
  logits = my_tower(data)
  ...
  train_step = ...
  with tf.control_dependencies([train_step]):
    return i+1
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. On my toy example, using that is twice as fast as using the Python loop.